# Как настроить фильтрацию include в pug для gulp

Tags: php, html, gulp, pug

Имеется таска для gulp,в которой при одном режиме работы происходит преобразование pug файлов html, а при другом - в php. Проблема в том, что для php файлов не нужны include файлы из pug, а нужны require с путями от корня (скомпилировать отдельно pug файлы в php не проблема), а для html соответственно всё должно быть по умолчанию. Один из вариантов было использовать код типа этого:

```
//
  <?
    require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/bitrix/header.php");
    $APPLICATION->SetPageProperty("title", "Главная");
    $APPLICATION->SetPageProperty("NOT_SHOW_NAV_CHAIN", "Y");
    $APPLICATION->SetTitle("Главная страница");
  ?>
include base_areas/header.pug
// ./header
```

,в котором для html генерится лишний код, но для разработки это не страшно, а вот для php файлов приходится для каждого такого участка кода раскомментировывать участок с php кодом, а участок с html кодом до знака ./ с названием класса удалять. Такой вариант долгий, нудный и не комильфо. Есть 2 мысли по направлению решения проблемы: 
1) ставить маркеры для require и include в pug файле, а при компиляции выбирать соответствующий блок (либо удалять не нужный)
2) использовать pug-php-filter для компиляции в php

```
:php
    echo "hello world";
```

Вопрос в следующем: какой из вариантов более оптимальный и если 1-й, то какой плагин можно использовать для фильтрации по флагам (маркерам), а если 2-й, то какой плагин поможет игнорировать include в pug файле при компиляции? 
При необходимости, могу скинуть ссылку на таску на Гитхабе

Answer (score 0, accepted):

решил сделать фильтр при помощи регулярок и плагина `gulp-replace`

```
let includeRegExp = /include.+\.pug/g;
function regExpFilter(str) {
    let output 
    let header = `| \
    <? \
    require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/bitrix/header.php"); \
    $APPLICATION->SetPageProperty("title", "Главная"); \
    $APPLICATION->SetTitle("Главная страница"); \
    ?>
    `
    let footer = `
        | <?require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/bitrix/footer.php");?>
    `;
    if (str.search(/base_areas\/header.pug/ig) != -1){
        output = header;
    } else if (str.search(/base_areas\/footer.pug/ig) != -1){
        output = footer;
    } else {
        let clearStr = str.split(' ')[1].replace(/\.pug/, '').replace(/\.\.\//, '')
        output = '| <?require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."'+ destPath +  clearStr + '.php");?>';
    }
    return output;
 }

gulp.task('pug',  function() {
    return gulp
        .src([projectPath + 'src/pug/**/*.pug'])
        .pipe(gulpif(!isDev, replace(includeRegExp, regExpFilter)))
        .pipe(pug({
            pretty: true
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(destPath))
});
```